# Getting Module Loading or Input variable error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I've configured the following variable in  module/variables.tf

```
variable "instance_name" {
    type = string
    default = "instance-1"
    description = "Name of the instance."
}
```

I refer to the variable in the same module module/main.tf as below

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "cloud_instance" {
    name = var.instance_name
}
```

However, when I run terraform init, I get the following error-

```
Error: Error parsing /module/main.tf: At 15:12: Unknown token: 15:12 IDENT var.instance_name
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What version of Terraform are you running? If it's pre 0.12 (just a beta right now) then that should be `name = "${var.instance_name}"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer variable as below to ensure expansion works correctly -

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "cloud_instance" {
    name = "${var.instance_name}"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using terraform 0.12.9 - I do not get this error on `init` or `plan` or `validate`, only on `0.12upgrade`.
Also the documentation shows that if the variable is not in a string, it is possible to pass it without quotation marks and curly braces.

So which is correct?